# Looping through Array to find same Values

Tags: python

i am relatively new to Python. I am trying to make a simple Slot Machine with Pygame. Everything except my function to check the win seems to work. I've tried several methods, but nothing seems to work.

I have an Array called `winningLines`. It looks like this:

> winningLines = [ [0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8, 9], [10, 11, 12, 13, 14] ]

Then i have a random generated Array looking like this:

> self.results = ['0', '0', '8', '8', '4', '1', '6', '2', '1', '8', '0', '0', '8', '3', '0']

The results are representing my Symbols on the Screen, so 0 = Symbol 1 (0.png), 1 = Symbol 2 (1.png) ...

I have a 5x3 grid (top left = 0, bottom right = 14). The result array is my grid.

So my grid looks like this:

| A | B | C | D | E |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 | 8 | 8 | 4 |
| 1 | 6 | 2 | 1 | 8 |
| 0 | 0 | 8 | 3 | 0 |

Now I want to check if the results have at least 3 of the same numbers (eg. A=0, B=0, C=0) or if there is a joker in between. The joker symbol/number is the 7, so the possible wins are eg. 000, 0000, 00000, 0007, 77007, 700, 00007 and so on)

At the moment my function looks like this:

```
def checkCombination(self, array):
    winningLines = [
        [0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
        [5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
        [10, 11, 12, 13, 14]
    ]

    joker = '7'

    for line in winningLines:
                numbers = [array[i] for i in line]
                for i in range(len(numbers) - 2):
                    if numbers[i] == numbers[i+1] == numbers[i+2] or joker in [numbers[i], numbers[i+1], numbers[i+2]]:
                        print("Winner")
                        return True
            return False
```

but it doesn't seem to work with the jokers or my symbols.

I hope you understood what I was trying to explain and could help me.

Thanks.

Doesn't work with jokers:

```
for line in winningLines:
    numbers = [array[i] for i in line]
    for i in range(len(numbers) - 2):
        if numbers[i] == numbers[i+1] == numbers[i+2] or joker in [numbers[i], numbers[i+1], numbers[i+2]]:
            print("Winner")
            return True
    return False
```

Returns True every time (even if there is no win):

```
for line in winningLines:
    values = [array[i] for i in line]
    for i in range(len(values) - 2):
        # Check if at least 3 consecutive values are the same or if there are two non-joker values that repeat twice
        if (values[i] == values[i + 1] == values[i + 2]) or \
           (values[i] != '7' and values[i] == values[i + 1] and values[i] != values[i + 2]) or \
           (values[i + 1] != '7' and values[i + 1] == values[i + 2] and values[i + 1] != values[i]):
                return True
    return False
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your code is almost correct, but you're missing the logic to check for consecutive numbers with jokers in between. To handle this, you can modify the checkCombination function like this:

```
def checkCombination(self, array):
winningLines = [
    [0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
    [5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
    [10, 11, 12, 13, 14]
]

joker = '7'

for line in winningLines:
    numbers = [array[i] for i in line]
    count = 0
    for i in range(len(numbers) - 1):
        if numbers[i] == numbers[i+1] or numbers[i] == joker or numbers[i+1] == joker:
            count += 1
        else:
            count = 0

        if count >= 2:  # At least 3 consecutive numbers
            print("Winner")
            return True

return False
```

This will iterate through the numbers array and check for consecutive numbers or jokers. The count variable keeps track of how many consecutive matches (including jokers) we have found. If count reaches 2 or more (indicating a match of at least 3), the function returns True.

Comment: `joker = '7'` means that `joker` is a string, so it will never compare equal to the values in the array, which are ints.

Answer (score 0):

You could leverage string operations (namely replace) to check for consecutive (at least 3) symbols by replacing the joker with the symbol to check.

```
winningLines = [ [0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8, 9], [10, 11, 12, 13, 14] ]
joker        = "7"

results      = ['0','0','8','8','4','1','6','2','1','8','0','0','7','3','0']

for linePositions in winningLines:
    line = "".join(results[pos] for pos in linePositions)
    for symbol in set(line):
        if symbol*3 in line.replace(joker,symbol):
            print("Winnner",line)

# Winnner 00730
```